# Matching two lists containing strings

Tags: python, list, match

I am a beginner in Python and had a problem with matching two lists containing strings,

i extracted the band names of a Landsat imagery from txt Metafile using regular expressions and had a list like this;

```
bant = ['LT5YYYYYYYYYYYYYXXX02_B1.TIF', 'LT5YYYYYYYYYYYYYXXX02_B2.TIF','LT5YYYYYYYYYYYYYXXX02_B3.TIF', 'LT5YYYYYYYYYYYYYXXX02_B4.TIF', 'LT5YYYYYYYYYYYYYXXX02_B5.TIF', 'LT5YYYYYYYYYYYYYXXX02_B6.TIF', 'LT5YYYYYYYYYYYYYXXX02_B7.TIF']
```

"YYYYYYYYYYYYY" are band specific names that changes from scene to scene.
and i assigned each string to a variable then to a new list.

```
        bant1 = bant[0]
        bant2 = bant[1]
               .
               .
        bant7 = bant[6]
        bant = [bant1,bant2,bant3,bant4,bant5,bant6,bant7]
```

Also by using Python os module i extracted the name of GeoTIFF files which are in same directory with txt Metafile like this;

```
import os
import re
def mtl():
file=[]
path = os.getcwd()
for filelist in os.listdir(path):
    if filelist.endswith(".TIF"):
        file.append(filelist)
```

with an output:

```
file = ['LT5YYYYYYYYYYYYYXXX02_B1.TIF', 'LT5YYYYYYYYYYYYYXXX02_B2.TIF']
```

so the problem that i got stuck is how can i compare these two lists, "bant" and "file". and print that the bands found in list are bant1, bant2. The number of strings in file list is changeable (Maybe some files are deleted by user so that not contained in file list).

Sorry for my English. Thanks for your helps

Comment: "and i assigned each string to a variable then to a new list." Wait… Why? There's clearly something you're trying to accomplish by doing that, but I can't imagine what it might be.

Comment: i want to show the user which bands are matched and thought that it would be easy if i do like that. i know maybe seems meaningless but as i said iam beginner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a side note, don't name a variable `file`—it's the name of a built-in type (in Python 2.x), so using it will lead to confusion. Also, it's a bit confusing to have an list of filenames and call it `file` instead of, say, `filenames`.

The naive way to do this is to use a nested `for` loop:

```
print('The bands found (or matches) are', end=' ')
for band in bant:
    for filename in filenames:
        if band == filename:
            print(band + ',', end=' ')
            break
print()
```

But you can use the `in` operator to make this much simpler:

```
print('The bands found (or matches) are', end=' ')
for band in bant:
    if band in filenames:
        print(band + ',', end=' ')
print()
```

If you're in Python 2.x instead of 3.x, you need to change this slightly:

```
print 'The bands found (or matches) are',
for band in bant:
    if band in filenames:
        print band + ',',
print
```

If you want to print the index instead of the value of each matched band, you can use `enumerate` to let you iterate over the indices and bands at the same time, like this:

```
print('The bands found (or matches) are', end=' ')
for i, band in enumerate(bant):
    if band in filenames:
        print('bant{},'.format(i), end=' ')
print()
```

Anyway, you may notice that this leaves an extra `,` at the end. In order to fix this, you'll need to keep track of whether you've printed any bands yet, and print a `,` before each band except the first. That gets ugly fast.

To solve that, you usually want to build up a collection of matches, and then you can join them together using `join`. Like this:

```
matches = []
for i, band in enumerate(bant):
    if band in filenames:
        matches.append('bant{}'.format(i))
print('The bands found (or matches) are', ', '.join(matches))
```

Much cleaner. But you can make this even simpler, by using a list comprehension:

```
matches = ['bant{}'.format(i) for i, band in enumerate(bant) if band in filenames] 
print('The bands found (or matches) are', ', '.join(matches))
```

If you read the comprehension and the equivalent list, you should be able to see how they're doing the same thing, but without the need to explicitly create the list and call `append` on it over and over.

Now, if you think about it, you may notice that you're doing a linear search the whole list of `filenames` once for each `band`. That doesn't matter much when there are only, say, 8 bands and 6 filenames, because it's at worst 48 comparisons, but what if there are 1000 of each? 1000000 comparisons will take a lot longer.

If you turn `filenames` into a `set`, each `band in filenames` only takes 1 comparison, instead of N comparisons, so if there are 1000 of each, you'll only do 1000 comparisons instead of 1000000. So:

```
filenameset = set(filename)
matches = ['bant{}.format(i) for i, band in enumerate(bant) if band in filenameset]
print('The bands found (or matches) are', ', '.join(matches))
```

There are further improvements you could make, but as long as you understand why this works, you're done.

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for [set intersection](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)?

```
In [16]: bant = ['LT5YYYYYYYYYYYYYXXX02_B1.TIF', 'LT5YYYYYYYYYYYYYXXX02_B2.TIF','LT5YYYYYYYYYYYYYXXX02_B3.TIF', 'LT5YYYYYYYYYYYYYXXX02_B4.TIF', 'LT5YYYYYYYYYYYYYXXX02_B5.TIF', 'LT5YYYYYYYYYYYYYXXX02_B6.TIF', 'LT5YYYYYYYYYYYYYXXX02_B7.TIF']

In [17]: file = ['LT5YYYYYYYYYYYYYXXX02_B1.TIF', 'LT5YYYYYYYYYYYYYXXX02_B2.TIF']

In [18]: set(bant).intersection(file)
Out[18]: set(['LT5YYYYYYYYYYYYYXXX02_B1.TIF', 'LT5YYYYYYYYYYYYYXXX02_B2.TIF'])
```

Note that `set`s are unordered, so the result returned by `set(bant).intersection(file)` may not correspond to the order given by `bant` or `file`. If you need to preserve the order of, say, `bant`, then you could use

```
fileset = set(file)
[b for b in bant if b in fileset]
```

---

Also, your method of defining `file` can be simplified to:

```
import glob
files = glob.glob('*.TIF')
```

---

It is possible to print

> The bands found (or matched) are bant1, bant2" by using the bant =
>   [bant1,bant2,bant3,bant4,bant5,bant6,bant7] list.

but before we do that, may I try to dissuade you from naming the items in `bant`: `bant1`, `bant2`, etc?

You say the number of items in `bant` is unknown until runtime, so how are you managing to give each item its own variable name? That is possible to do, but not necessary. Use Python indexing instead: `bant[0]` instead of `bant1`, `bant[1]` instead of `bant2`, etc.
By doing this you'll be able to program with `bant` much more easily than if you try to give each item in `bant` a numbered variable name.

Comment: <<standard disclaimer about ordering>>

Comment: Definitely yes. But in addition i want to print out a message like that "The bands found (or matched) are bant1, bant2" by using the bant = [bant1,bant2,bant3,bant4,bant5,bant6,bant7] list. Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: You really don't need to make `bant` a set here, as long as you make `fileset` into one. The latter makes everything simpler, and makes it O(N) instead of O(NM), which is important. But adding the former just lets you change a one-liner comprehension or `filter` into a slightly-shorted one-liner `intersection`, and I'm not sure that's worth it. (Especially since you lose the order, and if you want to get back the original indices, as the OP seems to want to, it gets complicated.) But otherwise, this is a good answer.